# How to save my app state when android system kill the app?

Tags: android

I know that onPause, onStop and onSavedInstanceData will be called when home button pressed, but how do i know when android system kill my app or destroy it in task manager?

Comment: onDestroy is called when your app is about to be killed

Comment: override `onDestroy()`

Comment: i have tried onDestroy to save my state, but sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @hello_world & Ishita : From the docs: `Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! ` ....that´s why sometimes it works to save and sometimes not. You should use like Arpit suggested in `onSaveInstance()`

Comment: @cmnewfan it is good practice to always save data in onPause and load in onResume. As onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called every time, but onPause is guaranteed to be called whenever your application loses focus. You can also use onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance for the same, but personally, i prefer onPause and onResume

Comment: @hello_world thanks for your advice, now i'm using onPause to save state and onResume to load state.

Comment: @cmnewfan glad i could help :) good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that when we press back button i.e., ourself close the activity then onSaveInstance() is not called.

Whenever android system destroy your activity because of low memory conditions onSaveInstance and then onRestoreInstance is called when it is recreated. Hence you should save the state in onSaveInstance.